# vector with constant size

Tags: c++, arrays, static, vector

I am looking for a C++ data type similar to `std::vector` but without the overhead related to dynamic resizing. The size of the container will remain constant over its lifetime. I considered using `boost::array`, however, that is not appropriate because it requires the size of the array to be known at compile time, which is not the case in my situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Measure if the dynamic resizing has really any performance impact before using anything non-standard.

Tip: With vector.reserve there will never be any array-reallocation.

Answer (score 10):

There's no overhead in reallocation if you don't reallocate std::vector. So either:

- construct the std::vector with a known size ahead (`std::vector x(100)`)
- call reserve(n) after construction to make sure that at least n elements can be pushed into the vector before reallocation occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The overhead induced by dynamic resizing capability of `std::vector` is virtually non-existent.

If you needed an array of compile-time size, looking for something more efficient than `std::vector` would indeed be a good idea in many cases.

But the difference between fixed run-time size and dynamic run-time size is negligible. `std::vector` is a perfect solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a template class based on ideas from STLSoft's `auto_buffer` (I cobbled together my own implementation from Matthew Wilson's Imperfect C++ book along with some ideas from the STLSoft implementation). It allocates the array by default on the stack (or embedded in the class object) if it's small enough (based on a template parameter you provide).  If your runtime allocation is larger than that, the array storage comes from the heap.

http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/classstlsoft_1_1auto__buffer.html

So the nice thing about this class is that for smaller small sizes, the allocation is essentially a no-op.

Comment: +1 for beating me to auto buffer. :) Boost has one [for review](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html).

Comment: @Zenikoder: `auto_buffer<>` isn't part of the STL.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the array is not known at compile time, then the only option in C++ is a dynamically-allocated array.  You can use a `std::vector` to guarantee RAII.  As others have said, the fact that `std::vector`s can be resized doesn't mean that you have to resize them.  Create the `std::vector` with the correct size, and then don't call anything that would resize it.